# Can a 9x9 sudoku with sum 45 and sum 285 of numbers squares of (rows,collunms,3x3) not be valid

Tags: sudoku

Its a program that check a sudoku solution if it is correct.

It checks

```
Rows,collums,3x3 grids if sum is 45 (1+2+3...+9=45)
Rows,collums,3x3 grids numbers in square if sum is 285 (1^2+2^2+3^2+...+9^2 = 285)
```

Is any way to fool that program with not a valid sudoku solution and make it think that is valid.

Comment: There are various vectors with duplicate digits from $1$ to $9$, such that the sum is $45$ and the sum of the squares is $285$, for example $[9,3,6,1,4,9,4,3,6]$. This is no proof that the program can fail, but at least a clear indication

Answer (score 2):

Using Peters example of a vector that satifies the conditions we can easily construct a "Sudoko" that fools your algorithm

\begin{matrix}
 9&  3&  6&  1&  4&  9&  4&  3&  6 \\
  1&  4&  9&  4&  3&  6&  9&  3&  6\\
  4&  3&  6&  9&  3&  6&  1&  4&  9\\
  3&  6&  1&  4&  9&  4&  3&  6&  9\\
  4&  9&  4&  3&  6&  9&  3&  6&  1\\
  3&  6&  9&  3&  6&  1&  4&  9&  4\\
  6&  1&  4&  9&  4&  3&  6&  9&  3\\
  9&  4&  3&  6&  9&  3&  6&  1&  4\\
  6&  9&  3&  6&  1&  4&  9&  4&  3
\end{matrix}